Differentiability of function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}; f(z)=z\exp(\bar{z})$

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $f(z)=z\exp(\bar{z})$. Identify the points where $f$ has complex derivative.

At $z=0$:
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0} 
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z\exp(\bar{z})}{z} 
= \lim_{z \to 0} \exp(\bar{z}) = 1
$$
So, $f$ is differentiable at $0$.
But for $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ with the prior knowledge that $\exp(\bar{z})$ is not differentiable anywhere, $f$ is not complex-differentiable at any non-zero complex number, because that'd imply $$
\exp(\bar{z}) = \frac{z\exp(\bar{z})}{z}
$$
would be complex-differentiable as it'd be the product of complex-differentiable functions on $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$.
So $f$ is only complex-differentiable at $0$. Is this argument correct?

Yes this argument is correct since $\mathbb{C}\setminus {0}$ is open

How do you know $\exp(\bar z)$ isn't differentiable? It's not, but that fact needs some kind of argument.

Yes your argument is correct. More directly: for any $z\in\Bbb C$,
$$\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\frac{(z+h)e^{\overline{z+h}}-ze^{\overline z}}h=ze^{\overline z}\frac{e^{\overline h}-1}h+e^{\overline{z+h}}$$ has a limit as $h\to0$ iff $z\frac{e^{\overline h}-1}h$ does, i.e. (since $\frac{e^{\overline h}-1}h$ doesn't) iff $z=0$.

Yes, this argument is correct. As pointed out in the comments, this argument implicitly uses that $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is open as in the definition of complex differentiability.
The fact that $\exp(\overline{z})$ is nowhere differentiable follows from the fact that it fails to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
